# Notepad++ display connection dialog. Cant restore message box

Tags: notepad++

Im having problems connecting to a server using notepad++ and NppFTP.

Somehow I turned off the dialog/message/connection box in notepad++ so I cant see why it's refusing the connection. Whether it's a key issue or some other type of issue.

Does anyone know how to restore the dialog/message/connection box in notepad++? I cant seem to find the solution.

Comment: *Show nessages window* is the rightmost icon there.

Comment: Well, that was easy enough. Sometimes I feel like such a dummy :-) Thank You very much

Answer (score 0):

*Show messages window* is the rightmost icon there:

[image]